# Amazon Dynamo DB price quiz

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I’m learning AWS Certified Developer Associate 2018 Practice Quiz.

> Question 1 "In DynamoDB, if you create a table and request 10 units of write capacity and 200 units of read capacity of provisioned throughput, how much would you be charged in US East (Northern Virginia) Region? "

1. $ 0.05 per hour
2. $ 0.10 per hour
3. $ 0.03 per hour
4. $ 0.15 per hour

My calculation is this.

> $0.00065 × 10 + $0.00013 × 200 = $0.0325 per hour

But the answer is this.

> $ 0.01 + (4 x $ 0.01) = $ 0.05 per hour "

What is “4”???

Knowledge Area: 
http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/

I didn’t understand 
Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You should ask this to whomever wrote the question. I would also ask them "What is the $0.01"? I suggest you do not spend much time worrying about this question. You will never be quizzed on prices. You will be expected to understand the concepts of RCU and WCU, but you will never need to memorize magical numbers like prices.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Oh my gosh... thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question seems premised on obsolete information.

[Previously](https://web.archive.org/web/20140105032747/https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/), DynamoDB capacity was sold in blocks of 10 WCU and 50 RCU, each of which was $0.0065.  (It may have been $0.01 several years ago, since AWS does sometimes decrease pricing when new technologies or efficiency gains permit it or this might be the result of rounding.)  The 4 is 200 ÷ 50.